# Spring Data JPA query return repeated row instead of actual data, why?

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Entity class

```
public class Event {

    @Id
    private String name;

    private String description;

    private Date eventDateTime;

    //getter and setter code
}
```

Service Class

```
EventService {

  @Autowired EventRepository eventRepository;

  List<Event> getEvents () {
     List<Event> events = eventRepository.findAll();

     return events;
  }
}
```

For sample data set:
Event ('add', '', '2018-01-01 00:00:10')
Event ('add', '', '2018-01-01 00:10:10')
Event ('delete', '', '2018-01-01 00:20:00')
Event ('edit', '', '2018-01-01 00:30:00')

JPA findAll() query return repeated rows:

Event ('add', '', '2018-01-01 00:00:10')
Event ('add', '', '2018-01-01 00:00:10')
Event ('add', '', '2018-01-01 00:00:10')
Event ('add', '', '2018-01-01 00:00:10')

Comment: Could you add the code where you are using the result of `findAll` ?

Comment: I added service class, where findAll() method called @Arnaud

Comment: JPA has no such "findAll". That is "Spring Data JPA", different API

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To avoid repeated (duplicate) data, we have to ensure there is a unique key and that will be annotated by @Id. In this example, **name** it self is not unique, that's why the result show duplicate data. **eventDateTime** is better choice as unique field.

```
public class Event {

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @Id
    private Date eventDateTime;

    //getter and setter code
}
```

Or, we can define a composite unique key with **name** and **eventDateTime**.

```
public class CompositeKey implements Serializable { 

    private String name;

    private Date eventDateTime;
}
```

Then, annotated **Event** class with @IdClass(CopositeKey.class) and both **name** and **eventDateTime** field with @Id

```
 @IdClass(CopositeKey.class)
 public class Event {
        @Id
        private String name;

        private String description;

        @Id
        private Date eventDateTime;

        //getter and setter code
    }
```

Comment: I get some rows of null using this method. Any idea?

Comment: Another way of defining composite primary key:

`public class Event {

    @EmbeddedId
    private IdClassName id;

    private String description;

    // getter and setter code
}

@Embeddable
public class IdClassName implements Serializable {

    private String name;

    private Date eventDateTime;
    
    // getter and setter code
}`

Answer (score 2):

Your `name`-column is the identifier of the entity (`@Id`), yet your sample-data contains the String `data` two times.

Identifiers have to be unique, if you manually assign them (i.e. not using generated identifier) it's the appliations responsibility to keep them unique.

If not strange behaviour may occur.

So you should either fix your sample data or use another column (with generated values) as the identifier of the entitiy.